# static NSMutableDictionary can only store one object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I tried creating a static NSMutableDictionary like this

```
static NSMutableDictionary* Textures;

+(Texture*) loadTexture: (NSString*) name path: (NSString*) path{
    CGImageRef imageReference = [[UIImage imageNamed:path] CGImage];

    GLKTextureInfo* textureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:imageReference options:nil error:NULL];

    Texture* texture = [[Texture alloc] init:textureInfo];

    if(!Textures) Textures = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [Textures setObject:texture forKey:name];

    return texture;
}
```

It seems I can only add one object to the dictionary but I believe I took care of creating a new one each time so I am stuck on why it seems I am only able to store one object in this dictionary. Also, it adds the first one and fails to add any subsequent calls.

Comment: Might not be the main issue, but this isn't thread safe. Is there a reason you're using lazy initialization of `Textures`, rather than instantiating it eagerly when the class is loaded?

Comment: I never initialize the class it's just a static method and when I add another texture I just call the method again

Comment: What is the indication that you can only add one object? How is it failing on subsequent attempts?

Comment: You may not initialize any objects of this class, but the class itself does get initialized when it's loaded into the objective C runtime. You can override the `+initialize` method to perform any class initialization you need, such as creating this dict https://stackoverflow.com/a/27859968/3141234

Comment: Diagnose with `NSLog(@"adding key %@ to dictionary with pointer %p", name, Textures);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From given part of code it is too hard to say what happening with you `Textures` static variable (it may be multithread problem, or event the same `name` value for each run), so I can suggest you to use following approach to fix problem:

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *) textures {
    static NSMutableDictionary *result = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        result = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    });
    return result;
}

+ (Texture*) loadTexture: (NSString*) name path: (NSString*) path {
    CGImageRef imageReference = [[UIImage imageNamed:path] CGImage];

    GLKTextureInfo* textureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:imageReference options:nil error:NULL];

    Texture* texture = [[Texture alloc] init:textureInfo];

    self.textures[name] = texture;

    return texture;
}
```